# How to get debugging symbols for Programs that Ship with Debian?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, debian, debug-symbols

Short Version: How can I get/add debugging symbols for programs that ship with Debian in order to debug with gdb?

Longer Version:  I'm using the Exim Mail Server that comes with Debian 7.7.0 and I'm in need of debugging symbols so that I can debug the program in gdb.  What would the easiest way to get these symbols be?  I've tried installing from source, but found it to be difficult due to the specific outdated version of Exim that I need and the configuration of the server when installing from source.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Many packages have an optional extra packages ending in `-dbg` which contains the debugging symbols. Per the [corresponding page on packages.debian.org](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=exim4-dbg), that is also the case for exim4.

So install exim4-dbg, and you should have the same symbols you would have gotten from compiling locally.

Comment: Is there some extra configuration necessary for gdb to load the symbols installed with exim4-dbg? GDB doesn't automatically load the symbols after exim4-dbg is installed.

Comment: I think it's just standard gdb which has been instrumented to look in the directory the symbols are being stored via this package -- but I haven't done this in a while either.

Comment: Restart gdb or use `nosharedlibrary` followed by `sharedlibrary .*`.  If that doesn't work then maybe your gdb was built with some wrong setting, and maybe `set debug-file-directory` to the right value will help.

Answer (score -1):

I think the objdump command could do the stuff you need. Check for its manual / try various flags and check if you get useful output from it.

Comment: objdump would need to use debugging information/the source code, which is what I'm trying to get in the first place.